# Apache Tomcat UNIX was shutdown, but web app still running

Tags: apache, tomcat

I found the  'shutdown.sh', and run it in Putty, Apache Tomcat stays up.  It is a very old server, and I can't tell where all the files are installed.  It looks like Apache was loaded more than once on this server.

Am I doing something wrong with the shutdown?

How can I tell which files the Apache Tomcat web is looking at?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the command

```
ps auxww | grep tomcat
```

This will give you a list of all the tomcat processes currently running on the box. Depending on how it is set up, the process will also show you where tomcat is running from, look for the "-Dcatalina.base=xxxxx" and "-Dcatalina.home=xxxxx" locations.

I find the shutdown script to be somewhat unreliable, so I get the PID for tomcat from the ps output and do

```
kill <pid>
```

It usually takes a few seconds to shut down completely, so I run the ps command again every few seconds until tomcat is no longer running. If after a while tomcat still hasn't shut down, you can do

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

which will force quit it.

HTH!